# CoreData deletion validation error: "Items cannot be deleted from links."

Tags: swift, core-data

My Core Data Model has a 1-to-many relationship between two entities with deletion rule set to "Cascade" (and the inverse to Nullify).

```
Game
Relationship: links, Destination: WebLink, Inverse: game
Optional: true
Delete Rule: Cascade
Type: To Many

WebLink
Relationship: game, Destination Game, Invserse: links
Optional: true
Delete Rule: Nullify
Type: To One
```

In my list view I'm using `.disabled(canDelete(item) == false)` to dis/enable a swipe action which deletes the Game entity with the implementation

```swift
private func canDelete(_ item: T) -> Bool {
    do {
        try item.validateForDelete()
        return true
    } catch {
        return false
    }
}
```

and (for both, Game and WebLink).

```swift
public override func validateForDelete() throws {
    try super.validateForDelete()
    // more to come
}
```

When `Game.links` is empty, it works fine. However, when there are WebLink objects related to a game, the validation fails and I never get the delete action. The error is

```
Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=1600 "Items cannot be deleted from links." ...
```

and it's thrown from Game's super class. The `WebLink.validateForDelete` is not called in this case.

If I recall correctly, `validateForDelete` should only throw when the delete rule is "Deny", but it's actually "Cascade".

Now: if I hardcode a `return true` at the top of the `canDelete` function and then perform the deletion of the game object, it works fine, i.e. the game is deleted and changes are saved.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I think the problem here is that you are calling validateForDelete outside of Core Data’s realm so to speak instead of Core Data calling it when you tell Core Data to save your changes. My recommendation is to avoid calling this method (and similar) yourself and instead use your own validation logic.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson thanks for the hint. Is it actually documented anywhere that this method shouldn't be used directly? Couldn't find it and it seemed to be the perfect way for it. Anyways it's strange that calling it on an object fails while deleting this object passes.

Comment: I did a quick search before posting my comment but I couldn't find anything documented about it, but the emphasis is on quick so... :) Without knowing how Core Data works on the inside I still assume that when you call save() on a managed object context Core Data does some preparations before performing the validations and the actual persisting like somehow locking the objects (or the whole context) that have changed so it can work in a safe mode and safely undo any changes in cases some validation fails. _continued_

Comment: ...When you call the validate method directly then the context isn't in that "mode" and the validation doesn't work or can't be performed in the same way. This is an assumption but I don't think I am completely off.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Will rewrite my code and prevent using this method directly to move forward for now.